# Why don't wavefunctions for electrons in neighbouring molecules overlap?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-chemistry

I've come across this picture of two linked molecules.  The intramolecular distances look similar to the intermolecular distances and it seems like that will be the case however you draw it because of the way the molecules wrap around each other.

I don't understand why electron wavefunctions stay localised in the bond region between nuclei in each molecule and don't interact with each other.  If we removed the electrons, held the nuclei fixed and then solved the Schrödinger equation for all the electrons in the resulting potential, I find it hard to believe that the lowest energy solution would pick out the red and blue molecules as in the picture.

[image: Molecular Solomon's Knot]

Comment: They don't stay localized

Comment: *"I find it hard to believe that [...]"* Is always a sign of trouble. Have you actually done the computation? Have you included the multi-electron effect in your computation? If either answer is "no" then you are at best guessing on the basis of heuristics and experience (you do have lots of experience, right?) or at worst taking a substantial risk of making a fool of yourself. But any way 'round, argument from incredulity is a fallacy.

Comment: Try understanding it with two hydrogen atoms first.